# Sort one array according to the other array using quick sort in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to sort `a`, according to ascending order of `c`. `c` gets sorted by this method, but `a` doesn't, `a` has only four unsorted elements at the end of code. What changes should I make?

```
var a = ['e','b','d','a','f','g','c'];
function quick_Sort(origArray,a) {
 var i;
 var length = origArray.length;
 if (origArray.length <= 1) { 
    return [origArray, a];
 } else {

    var left = [];
    var right = [];
    var left1 = [];
    var right1 = [];
    var newArray = [];
    var newArray1 = [];
    var pivot = origArray.pop();
    var pivot1 = a.pop();

    for (i = 0; i < length-1; i++) {
        if (origArray[i] <= pivot) {
            left.push(origArray[i]);
    left1.push(a[i]);
        } else {
            right.push(origArray[i]);
    right1.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
    return [newArray.concat((quick_Sort(left, left1)[0]), pivot, (quick_Sort(right, right1)[0])),newArray1.concat((quick_Sort(left, left1)[1]), pivot1, (quick_Sort(right, right1)[1]))];
 }
}

var c = [3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1 ];

console.log("Original array: " + c);
console.log("Original array: " + a);
var e = quick_Sort(c,a);
c = e[0];
a = e[1];
console.log("Sorted array: " + c);
console.log("Sorted array: " + a);
```

Comment: "I want to sort a, according to ascending order of c" This part is not very clear for me. As in your question sorted 'c' would be [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]. So what should be sorted 'a' in this case?

Comment: `a` will be sorted in the same order as `c` gets sorted. `a` will be `['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort `a` from the corresponding value of `c` you can:

```js
var a = ['e','b','d','a','f','g','c'];
var c = [3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1 ];
 
var [sortedA, sortedC] = a.map((v,i) => [ v, c[i] ] )   //Pair the a and c
           .sort((x,y)=>x[1] - y[1])             //Sort the array based on the c value
           .reduce((c,v) => {
               c[0].push( v[0] );
               c[1].push( v[1] );
               return c;
           }, [[],[]]);                          //Seperate the a and c

console.log( sortedA );
console.log( sortedC );
```

Comment: what is `b` here?

Comment: @aQwusjargon to avoid confusion I renamed the variables to `x` and `y` on the sort

Comment: On js sort, it takes 2 variables that you need to compare. Here is a doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: No need to sort `c`. This script does the sorting.

Comment: @aQwusjargon Please check the code. This will return the sortedA and sortedC